# How to convert html5 presentation (slideshow) to mp4 for uploading to youtube?

Tags: html, youtube, mp4

I have a simple html5 slideshow that I want to upload to my youtube channel.

I tried a screen capture with camtasia, hoping to produce a .mp4 file for uploading to youtube.

However the quality of the output is not the same as the original html5 presentation (staggered transitions).

Any suggestions on how to convert an html5 slideshow to a decent quality .mp4 video that I can upload to youtube ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to convert html to a video file but there are many other ways to create a video slide show.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I know there are other solutions, however I need to be able to automate the slideshow with php (or similar) because I need to include some DB info, and then export the result of each slideshow. I thus would need a program that allows me to import html5, CSS and JS files, before converting. A simple photo slideshow wouldn't make it.